# Nested structures with QRadioButtons

Tags: qt, layout, qradiobutton

I would like to achieve something similar to this picture:

[image]

except that the top level ("Adress bar", "forms" and "User names...") should be radio buttons.

The idea is that the sublevels should get enabled or disabled depending on the state of the radiobuttons. And the sublevels should be shifted to the right as on the picture.

Can that be done Qt in an elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

I would say a simple `QVBoxLayout` for the top level and each "sublevel" has a `QHBoxLayout` with a fixed sized spacer item as the first child and a `QVBoxLayout` containing the sub options.

Disabling all sub options can then simply be done by disabling the "sublevel" widget.

Answer (score 0):

Just put those sub-items (like "Browsing history", "Favorites", ...) into a separated `QWidget` and connect that widget's `QWidget::setEnabled()` slot with the "Adress bar" radio-button's `QAbstractButton::toggled()` signal.

This is a Qt Designer's **.ui** file (with working signal-slot connection, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Designer) that demonstrates the idea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>170</width>
    <height>178</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton">
     <property name="text">
      <string>RadioButton</string>
     </property>
     <property name="checked">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
        <property name="text">
         <string>CheckBox</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_2">
        <property name="text">
         <string>CheckBox</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_3">
        <property name="text">
         <string>CheckBox</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_2">
     <property name="text">
      <string>RadioButton</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_3">
     <property name="text">
      <string>RadioButton</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>radioButton</sender>
   <signal>toggled(bool)</signal>
   <receiver>widget</receiver>
   <slot>setEnabled(bool)</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>84</x>
     <y>17</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>84</x>
     <y>77</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```